# How can I hide file tags?

Tags: macos, privacy, finder-tag

I'm tagging USB and network drives in Mavericks, and I would like the tags to disappear from my Mac when the drives are disconnected. Is this possible?

Comment: In Ask Different Chat, an idea: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13652564#13652564 (sorry, I can't provide test results at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

1. Disconnect the external drive.
2. Navigate to Finder -> Preferences... -> Tags.
3. Delete the desired tag. Confirm.
4. Reconnect the external drive.
5. The tag will reappear.
6. Disconnect the external drive.
7. The tag will disappear.

I'm curious if there's a more permanent solution, such as a way to create tags so that they're transient in the first place.